# Testing a binomial model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, experiment-design, generalized-linear-model

I have a computational experiment that takes a size parameter $s$ and returns true or false.

It has been suggested that the result of the experiment is independent of $s$, but I don't think so.  I expect a general decrease in the numbers, though only logarithmically dependent on $s$.  (This makes it hard to detect and is the essential reason for my posting -- a larger effect would be easier to detect.)

For s = 5..30 I have generated 1000 samples for which I give the number of occurrences, respectively:

108, 108, 99, 99, 98, 87, 82, 85, 84, 94, 97, 87, 86, 102, 82, 84, 83, 87, 75, 69, 66, 79, 91, 81, 74, 74

Another wrinkle: the time needed to generate the samples depends on the size parameter.  Making 1000 tests at size 10 took less than a second; at size 30 it takes nearly a minute.  So I could generate many more examples at small sizes if that would be helpful.  ($s$ relates to $10^s$, so I can't pick too many more than $10^s$ for a given $s$.  But I could run a billion tests at s = 10 without trouble [in a week or two].)

The flip side, of course, is that it's difficult to generate large examples, even though those are the ones that would be most useful.  With a bit more effort (half a dozen processor-hours) I was able to do 1000 tests at higher levels:
s = 40: 75
s = 45: 81
s = 50: 74
s = 55: 73
s = 60: 74
s = 65: 68

So my question: How should I design an experiment to decide if these are identically distributed?  Once I have my data, how can I decide (for some $\alpha$) whether to reject or not reject the hypothesis that the distributions are identical, i.e., independent of $s$?

For example, I could continue to generate data for 1000 tests at each value of $s$ from 31 to 70.  But given the increasing time needed as the parameter increases I'm not sure that this is an appropriate way to sample the data.  But once I introduce non-uniformity I'm not sure what testing technique would be appropriate.  (I'm a statistical neophyte.)

Comment: You already have reasonably strong evidence of the logarithmic trend, even using only the data for s = 10,20,30,40,50 (which avoids worries about high leverage with s=40 or 50) and very strong evidence that there is *some* kind of trend.  In addition to that, what more are you looking for?

Comment: @whuber: Ideally, evidence whether the probability is decreasing inversely proportional to the logarithm.

Comment: The evidence for a log trend is not there in the 5..30 dataset (which shows a downward trend but suggests it's linear, not logarithmic) but with the addition of s=40,50 it is there.  The problems are that (1) the evidence is fairly sensitive to the two results at 40 and 50, implying you could use more data for higher s (but this sense of "sensitive" is *not* what experimental design formulas address!) and (2) it could help to confirm the logarithmic trend at intermediate values (in the range 30..50) and at more extreme values than 50, if they are of interest.

Comment: @whuber: OK, I put in some crunching time and generated more data at higher levels.  If more would be needed I could generate data for higher numbers (say, 1000 tests at s = 70, 75, 80) or increase the data for existing points from 1000 to 10,000 points with approximately equal effort.

Comment: @whuber: As I mentioned in a comment to one of the answers, there cannot be a linear trend unless it is constant, as it would cause the probability of the trait to go over 100% or under 0%.  A hyperbolic trend is _a priori_ possible, but linear is not.  The inverse log trend comes from theory rather than looking at the data; I might do some work to see if I can get more specific predictions from that model and compare to the data.

Comment: I make no claim about any trends; I only said that the data for s in 5..30 provide evidence for a linear trend *within that interval*.  It's foolish to extrapolate far outside the range of data you have, as you know: that's your point.  That's why I suggested you might be interested in values more extreme than 50, because you definitely would like to bracket the range of s you are interested in modeling.  (Incidentally, many experimental design formulas wind up telling you to take all your measurements at the two extremes and none in middle.)

Comment: I did add measurements up to 65 above; I hope to have measurements up to 80 tomorrow.  But what I actually want is information about how it performs around, say, 5000 -- a range that is entirely infeasible to test.  Of course statistics alone can't do this, I need domain-specific knowledge.  I have this, but I'd like to make sure my conclusions are reasonable based on the data I can test.

Comment: Can you perform even a *single* test for $s=5000$?

Comment: No.  At s = 150 I could perform maybe one test per day; at s = 300 I could not test anything.

Comment: Then there's really not much you can say beyond $s=300$ except completely on faith.

Comment: There's quite a bit I can say.  For example, I can say that the probability is greater than 0 for any positive s, even though I can't compute that far.  At present I can't prove the thing I want so I'm looking for statistical support, but it's just that -- support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good choice to analyze these data would be a [generalized linear model for a binomial response and a logit link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Binomial_data).  Conceptually it's simple: it says that each test has a chance $f(s)$ of succeeding, so that 1000 runs at a given value of $s$ should behave like 1000 flips of a coin having an $f(s)$ chance of success.  The chances are not expressed as probabilities, but as the logarithms of the odds: that's the logit.  Your supposition is that these log odds are a linear function of $\log(s)$.  The function $f$ is the combination of this logarithm and the logit.

However, you don't really need this level of sophistication because (a) you have run the same number of tests each time, (b) the number is large enough that the response counts are not small, and (c) the expected changes in response rate and its variance for this range of $s$ (from 5 through 70) are small.  Thus you will get essentially the same results if you do ordinary least squares regression of the [logit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) of response/1000 against $\log(s)$.  This is simple enough even to do with a spreadsheet.

[image: scatterplot 1]

This plot shows the re-expressed data and their least squares fit.  It's a good fit; the residuals tend to be evenly scattered around it; and no points are extremely far to the right or the left.  There is a slight tendency for residuals to be positive for both small and large values of $\log(s)$, hinting at a quadratic term in $\log(s)$.  If that's a possibility, run more experiments for $s \le 10$ and $s \ge 50$.

The OLS table is

```
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         lns |   -.173364   .0238979    -7.25   0.000      -.22217   -.1245579
       _cons |  -1.874851   .0727821   -25.76   0.000    -2.023492    -1.72621
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and, for comparison, the (more accurate) GLM table is

```
    response |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         lns |  -.1758287   .0305201    -5.76   0.000    -.2356469   -.1160104
       _cons |  -1.864569    .091082   -20.47   0.000    -2.043086   -1.686051
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The closeness of the coefficients show that both techniques are fitting the same curve.  The logarithmic term is highly significant for both.  OLS is a little overconfident (it gets more extreme p values), but that doesn't matter here.

As a final check, we can back-transform the fit.  I have placed two bands at one standard deviation (as predicted by the fit at each point: the bands actually get narrower as $s$ gets larger).  If anything, the scatter is *too* tight: we would expect one-third or so of these 32 points, or 10 of them, to lie beyond the bands, but only 5 do.  (I wouldn't read much into that, but I would be worried if the opposite were true: if the majority of points fell outside these bands, I would worry about the accuracy of the binomial model.)

[image: scatterplot 2]

If you have the capability of running a GLM, then you can use it to analyze a dataset in which the numbers of tests per value of $s$ vary.  Because you already have about six times as much data as you need (to show the log trend is significant), I would recommend substantially reducing the sizes of future experiments, perhaps down to 100 or even less, rather than 1000 at a time.  You certainly can optimize your experimentation to get the most additional information for the extra work, but if you're almost done, it's less work overall just to continue with these rough heuristics.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the data is sufficiently strong that you can get by with testing a much weaker assertion than what you are actually interested in. In this case, a very weak consequence of the null hypothesis (the probability is independent of $s$) would be that the cases $5 \leq s \leq 17$ and $18 \leq s \leq 30$ have the same probability of success. You can test this with a two-sample t test; acceptance of the null hypothesis wouldn't tell you very much (only that this weak consequence is acceptable), but rejection of the consequence implies rejection of the original, stronger, null hypothesis. I ran this test in two different ways - one by testing the $2 \times 13$ numbers of successes, and one by testing the $2 \times 13000$ zeroes and ones for the individual outcomes. In both cases, the $p$-value was pretty small (0.0016 and 0.00024, respectively), so for $\alpha > 0.00024$ I believe we can reject the hypothesis.

Of course there are many situations where this type of laziness doesn't work; then we need more advanced analysis to give us a definitive result. But sometimes a lazy approach is good enough.

(P.S. - I later realized that a cheap strengthening of the test would be to make it one-sided; that should improve the values even further with hardly any extra effort.)

Comment: Good -- glad to know I don't need a more powerful approach.  Do you think it's feasible to test the data for a logarithmic fit?  Something like probability ~ a/log s.

Comment: A standard quick approach is to divide the data into thirds along the s axis (with the intention of comparing the first and last thirds with a test of central tendency, usually a nonparametric one).  If you do this for the 5..30 data and produce three side-by-side boxplots, the trend will be clear and convincing.  The middle one, though, will *not* suggest a logarithmic tendency.

Answer (score 1):

This is a neat design of experiments exercise. You have a regression model, something like ${\rm Prob}[{\rm test}=1|s] = a + b \log s + \epsilon$, and you want to estimate the parameter $b$ subject to computational costs. This is akin to [Neymann-Chuprow allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination#Stratified_sample_size) in survey statistics. As a first approximation, you can utilize Neymann formula with $h$ being each individual value of $s$ and $C(s)$ being the time it takes to produce a single test. Basically, you'd want to take the number of tests that is inversely proportional to $\sqrt{C(s)}$. As a more accurate approximation, you can develop a model for the cost as a function of $s$, and plug it into the variance expression for the coefficient $b$ (the corresponding entry in the standard $\sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1}$ formula assuming the variances are constant... which is not exactly right, but for a small effect, is not a terrible approximation).

**Update**: per whuber's suggestion in the comments section: it might be worth checking the assumptions of your model. As long as we are in an agreement that this is an experimental design situation, the (rather small) subfield of the expertimental design literature that deals with deviations from the function form is called "robust design" literature. If you knew you had a linear trend, the best design would be to collect the data in the two extreme points ($s=5$ and $s=30$). However, to test for deviations from linearity, you would need to use a design that spreads the points across the whole domain (in the simple case of constant costs and constant variance, uniformly between the two extremes). For you, this basically means an extended analysis of the (existing or to be collected) data, in which you would run say a regression $\mbox{Prob}[\mbox{test}=1|s] = b_0 + b_1 s + b_2 s^2 + b_3 s^3 + \epsilon$ to see if you have higher order wiggles in your line (or add your favorite $\log s$ term there if you insist on the log dependence).

Comment: (The link associated with Neymann-Chuprow allocation makes no mention of it.)  This is a nice start.  It would be helpful to add a few remarks about the need to collect data to test the model specification: often, optimal designs are inadequate for this (crucial) purpose.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Is there a good introduction to Neymann-Chuprow somewhere?  As I said, I have very little statistical background so simple is good.

Comment: @Charles, you can take a look at http://www.amazon.com/Sampling-Analysis-Advanced-Sharon-Lohr/dp/0495105279 or http://www.amazon.com/Sampling-Techniques-3rd-William-Cochran/dp/047116240X.

Comment: @whuber: I can link to a more specific subsection of the Wikipedia article. It is (inappropriately) called "Neyman's allocation" there. I will also add a couple of word about robust designs.

Comment: In response to the update: I absolutely guarantee that the trend is not linear (unless it is constant), as that would cause the probability that the tested quality is present to be negative for large s.  Needless to say, this does not happen.  As my primary interest is extrapolation to large s (which I cannot reasonably sample because of the time required) I cannot ignore this effect.

Comment: Do you have a substantive theory that states that the dependence must be logarithmic? E.g., if you were dealing with sort algorithms, there are good reasons to state that the model must have the form time$=a + b n + c n \log n + $random noise (and you'd expect that contributions of $a$ and $b$ would be small compared to $c$). Or is your logarithmic assumption just a convenient one?

Comment: @StasK: It's based on the Hardy-Ramanujan theorem and some handwaving. :)  It was a theoretical prediction made before I calculated the data.